# How to migrate a Homebrew environment to another computer?

Tags: homebrew

What is the preferred method of exporting a homebrew environment so I can synchronize my workspace between computers? Seems like there should be something similar to `composer.lock` or  `pip freeze`. Is there a better way than `brew list > brews.txt`?

Answer (score 22):

There is a better way: `brew leaves`.

This command prints a simple list of installed formulae which are not dependencies of any other formulae. Essentially this lists everything that was manually installed or is a leftover dependency from a removed formula.

```
$ brew leaves
apple-gcc42
bash-completion
brew-cask
git
[...]
```

There's no built-in means of using `brew leaves` output to install, but just having a clean list of manually-installed formulae is a step in the right direction.

Thanks to this Gabe Berke-Williams for writing about this: http://robots.thoughtbot.com/brew-leaves

Comment: On computer A: `brew leaves > my_brews`. Then transfer the `my_brews` file to computer B. There, do `xargs brew install < my_brews`.

Answer (score 1):

There is not a better way, and there are no current plans to make one.

[Source](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/issues/17771)

Answer (score 0):

Use git! Maintaining repos for environment setup scripts is a pretty slick approach.

I highly recommend using a script to set up a development environment in the first place. [thoughtbot](https://github.com/thoughtbot/laptop) has a really lightweight approach that provisions a development environment, including a bunch of brew formulas. GitHub just open sourced boxen for this (and much more), but it has a somewhat steeper learning curve.

As you can see from the thoughtbot/latop readme, the entire install is a one-liner. If you want different packages, fork the repo and add whatever you use. This only covers the initial install, but it is a fantastic start.

For ongoing synchronization of development environments, including updating your preferred homebrew setup, you might want to try a 'dotfiles' approach. Zach Holman has a great approach detailed [here](https://github.com/holman/dotfiles).

If you want to tweak or update anything, just make the appropriate changes to the script (holman's dot script does the ongoing update stuff). Commit, push, pull down from any other environments.